# Wifi Issues with Elementary OS

Tags: wifi

Whenever I connect to my network, it connects fine for about 10-15 minutes until it still shows up as connected to the network in the upper-right corner but if I try to do anything that requires internet, it just doesn't work and says I'm not connected. Then after about 15 seconds, it pops up a notification saying I'm disconnected from the network. Please help me, I really just want to use my computer but I can barely do anything.

Answer (score 1):

this sounds like a driver issue, do you know which wireless chip you have 
I'll give you and update on what to do based on that

lspci
lspci -v
lspci -v | less

Try doing that and post a screenshot with what pops up
I'll know how to help you after that